# How to get the full size of a (changeable) component inside a JScrollPane?

Tags: java, size, components, jscrollpane

My code is like this:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();

JPanel panel = new JPanel();

JTextPane text = new JTextPane();
text.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,260));
text.setContentType("text/html");
text.setEditable(false);
text.setText("some random thing makes this pane bigger than its perferred size");

JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(text);

panel.add(scroll);

frame.add(panel);
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.pack();
frame.validate();
```

My problem is I don't know how to get the real size of the `JTextPane` (the *text* here). I've tried all `getSizes` & `getVisibleRects`, `scroll.getViewport().getViewSize()`... but they're all returning `[200,260]`. Could someone help me solve this? I really appreciate any help you can provide.

EDIT: I found out the problem: My `getSizes` requests were executed before the frame was validated.
My runnable testing code:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;

public class Abcd {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    JTextPane text = new JTextPane();
    text.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,126));
    text.setContentType("text/html");
    text.setEditable(false);

    //Alicia Vikander's photo. She's cute anw.
    String tmp = "<a href=\"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b2/Alicia_Vikander.jpg/220px-Alicia_Vikander.jpg\"><img src=\"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b2/Alicia_Vikander.jpg/220px-Alicia_Vikander.jpg\"/></a>";
    //text.setText("asdf fssdfsdf sfdsdf sd sdf sfasdf fssdfsdf sfdsdf sd sdf sfasdf fssdfsdf sfdsdf sd sdf sfasdf fssdfsdf sfdsdf sd sdf sfasdf fssdfsdf sfdsdf sd sdf sfasdf fssdfsdf sfdsdf sd sdf sfasdf fssdfsdf sfdsdf sd sdf sfasdf fssdfsdf sfdsdf sd sdf sfasdf fssdfsdf sfdsdf sd sdf sfasdf fssdfsdf sfdsdf sd sdf sfasdf fssdfsdf sfdsdf sd sdf sfasdf fssdfsdf sfdsdf sd sdf sfasdf fssdfsdf sfdsdf sd sdf sf");
    text.setText(tmp);
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(text);
    scroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,126));

    panel.add(scroll);

    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.pack();
    frame.validate();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    for (double i = 0; i < 1000; i = i +  0.0001){
        System.out.print(text.getHeight()+"\n");            
        if (text.getHeight()!=123){   //3 pixels for the scrollpane's border i guessed
            System.out.print("i = "+i+", height = "+text.getHeight());
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

In my computer `i` is around 50 - 100. So my new problem is: Is there anyway I could get the realsize as soon as i can but still make sure the frame is validated?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your test wasn't actually changing `text`'s size when I ran it, instead it was just wrapping to a new line.  I multiplied your testing text by 50 and then it changed size and `text.getSize()` changed it's output accordingly

Comment: `but they're all returning [200,260]. ` Don't use the `setPreferredSize()` method.

Comment: Thank you all guys. I could finally find out why they were returned `[200,260]` instead of the real size: The `getSizes` requests were done before the frame was validated. 
I've editted the question, putting my runnable example (the original one was kinda meager, my mistake). My problem now is how to make sure i could get the size when the frame was already validated.
Thanks again for your helps.

Answer (score 0):

I highly suggest you start using different [Layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

If I tweek your code some:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();

final JTextPane text = new JTextPane();
text.setContentType("text/html");
text.setEditable(false);
text.setText("some random thing makes this pane bigger than its perferred size");

final JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(text);
scroll.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter()  {
        @Override
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Size of JScrollPane is: " + scroll.getSize());
            System.out.println("Size of JTextPane is: " + text.getSize());
        }
});

frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
frame.add(scroll,BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

We will have the size of the scroll component calling its `scroll.getSize()` and the size of the text component calling its `text.getSize()`

Comment: I've edited my post (my old one was too meager, my mistake). Well it's my new (real) problem. Hope you could help me to solve it. Thanks again for your helps

Comment: @HaM.1 Can't really understand you for loop???, furthermore you insist in not using layout manager.... (please consider to use it), Since size can vary if component is re-sized, I would use a ComponentListener as in example to understand what size they have...

Comment: I'm using the `for` loop just instead of the timertask or other things to show the result's changing through time. My using code was actually running and the size did change but the `for` loop showed me that my next line was executed when the frame was still being validated. The final result is supposed to be `height = 283` but i could only get it when the index was running to 50 or sth (`123` is the original height without text inside). I've tried using layout manager but it didn't help much so i didn't put it into the sample code.

Comment: This is not really correct coding style consider using Listeners example validate before displaying and do then execute your code in componentShown(ComponentEvent e) (ComponentListener)